# Designing a Visual Studio 2010 Integration Package

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx, visual-studio-sdk

I'd like to get started with the Visual Studio 2010 SDK and creating integration packages. All I would like to do for now is provide a new project type and language service. However, I don't know how I should design it...

The package will provide an editor for a programming language that compiles for x86 or ARM processors. The problem is that there are a few language differences depending on which processor you're developing for. I'd rather not have a separate project type for each architecture, however. Preferably, the programmer chooses the architecture when they create the project and the package automatically loads up the specific parts such as the correct language service, configuration settings, and whatever custom tools and dialogs are associated with that architecture.

How would I go about doing this? I've read about "flavored projects", but I don't really understand how to implement them. Is that what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points to note to get you headed in the right direction:

- The interfaces for a language service to hook into the editor have completely changed for VS 2010. I would recommended asking questions on the [VS Editor Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditorprerelease/threads) where all the devs for the core VS editor hang out for the speediest answers since the documentation and samples are still incomplete at this point. (There is a compatibility layer to support "old" language services, but you'd be better off just using the new interfaces since you're starting from scratch.)
- A "flavored project" (referred to in the docs as a Project Subtype) is a way to add/remove functionality from an existing project system. For example, there is are project flavors for Web Projects, WPF, Devices, Database, etc.... on top of CSProj and VBProj. In these cases C# and VB are the "base" project systems and WPF, Web, Database are flavors that extend the base C#/VB project systems. Since you have a custom language, you should implement your own base project system. Your best bet for starting from scratch would be to build something based off the [MPFProj source library](http://mpfproj10.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on something very similar -- here is my starting point:

http://blogs.msdn.com/noahric/archive/2010/02/15/markdown-part-4-outlining.aspx

It's a very nice example of how to implement an editor extension.